# Show Key Value Pair Values of Dictionary on Text Writer

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

When I write to the trace logs of CRM, I am tracing to see the values of a dictionary.

I see the following:

> Key:
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Double]
>   Value:
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Double]

I have looked at previous answers and says to use:

```
myDictionary.Keys, myDictionary.Values
```

Which I have done as follows:

```
tracer.Trace("Key: {0} Value: {1}", currentSiblingHours.Keys, currentSiblingHours.Values);
```

Why am I not seeing the actually keys and values still?

Comment: Why the -1? This was a completely valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
foreach(var keyValuePair in myDictionary)
       tracer.Trace("Key: {0} Value: {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.  CRM would require an ILMerge to use the Newtonsoft.JSON assembly.  It was a pain for me before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a [`KeyCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keycollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) and your code is calling `ToString()` on that object which hasn't been implemented hence why you have a type name in your output. You could either serialise the dictionary to JSON:

```
tracer.Trace("Data: {0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentSiblingHours);
```

Or you can use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
tracer.Trace("Key: {0} Value: {1}", 
    string.Join(", ", currentSiblingHours.Keys), 
    string.Join(", ", currentSiblingHours.Values));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `Keys` and `Values` are collections. The default `ToString()` will simply return their type. If you want to include in a string the keys and values, or the dictionary itself, you should somehow serialize it - the easiest way is to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` from Newtonsoft's library.